# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Tags: php, mysqli

in this case my queries work fine i have tested them on mysql.

First I have a custom query function that looks like this in the MySQLDatabase class

```
public function query($query) {
    $this->last_query = $query;
    $resultado = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
    $this->confirm_query($resultado);
    return $resultado;
}

private function confirm_query($result) {
    if ($result  === FALSE) {
        print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
        $output = "Error on query".  mysqli_error($this->connection)."<br/>";
        $output .= "Last query : ".$this->last_query;
        die($output);
    }
}

public function fetch_array($result_set){

    return mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);

}
```

Then i have a class called User which use the MYSQL class

```
    public static function find_by_id($id=0){
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database -> query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$id}");
    $found = $database ->fetch_array($result_set);
    return $found;
}
```

And finally i call the methods in my index.php in this way

```
$result_set = User::find_by_id(1);
$found_user = $database ->fetch_array($result_set);
```

Here are some facts :
1.- This warning happens when I insert an id value that exists in my database

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   array given

2.- This warning happens when I insert an id value that doesn´t exists in my database.

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, null given

The conclusion is that mysqli_query is not returning results but an result object  like this in the case it finds a row in the database with certain id .

> mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 5
>   [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `found_by_id` method is already calling `mysqli::fetch_array` here:

```
$found = $database ->fetch_array($result_set);
```

It returns the fetched array, if you then write:

```
$result_set = User::find_by_id(1);
$found_user = $database ->fetch_array($result_set);//fetch_array again
```

you're passing the fetched array back to fetch_array, which doesn't work

It's exactly the same as writing this:

```
$result_set = $database -> query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1");
$found = $database ->fetch_array($result_set);
$found_user = $database->fetch_array($found);//<-- second call...
```

Comment: You were all right i was passing the array to the fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
$result_set = User::find_by_id(1);

if($result_set){

      $found_user = $database ->fetch_array($result_set);

}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, cf my answer: `fetch_array` is called twice

Comment: i think some times $result_set does not return any value. so that it gives error.. like that..

Comment: _read_ the error message carefully: _"mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, **array given**"_ <-- array given means OP is passing an array here `$database->fetch_array($result_set);`, which means `$result_set` **is an array** not a result resource